# Nokogiri XML parse and win1251

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I'm using Ruby and trying to use Nokogiri for XML

I have such server's response

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?><response><Purpose>\xD0\x9B\xD0\x98\xD0\xA7\xD0\x9D\xD0\xAB\xD0\x95</Purpose><retval>0</retval></response>
```

and Nokogiri::XML can't parse it

In a rails console:

```
    a = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"windows-1251\"?><response><Purpose>\xD0\x9B\xD0\x98\xD0\xA7\xD0\x9D\xD0\xAB\xD0\x95</Purpose><retval>0</retval></response>"

    #=> "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"windows-1251\"?><response><Purpose>ЛИЧНЫЕ</Purpose><retval>0</retval></response>"

    doc = Nokogiri::XML(a)
    #=> #<Nokogiri::XML::Document:0x6181fc2 name="document">
    doc.errors
    #=> [#<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: input conversion failed due to input error, bytes 0x98 0xD0 0xA7 0xD0>, #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: switching encoding: encoder error>, #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: Blank needed here>, #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: input conversion failed due to input error, bytes 0x98 0xD0 0xA7 0xD0>, #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: encoder error>, #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: parsing XML declaration: '?>' expected>, #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: internal error: Huge input lookup>, #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: internal error: Huge input lookup>, #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: internal error: Huge input lookup>, #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: Start tag expected, '<' not found>]
```

it seems, it's problem with **\xD0\x98**

how can i solve this problem?

Comment: Can you try `Nokogiri::XML(a, nil, "windows-1251" )` ?

Comment: yes i can, but in this case i will lose a full value <Purpose>

Comment: Isn't this valid UTF-8 sequence `ЛИЧНЫЕ`? The XML document is telling you the wrong encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The document is perfectly `UTF8`-encoded. You need to force `UTF-8` *for Nokogiri*:

```
a = <<EOT
   <?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"windows-1251\"?>
   <response>
     <Purpose>\xD0\x9B\xD0\x98\xD0\xA7\xD0\x9D\xD0\xAB\xD0\x95</Purpose>
   <retval>0</retval>
   </response>
EOT

#                           ⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓
doc = Nokogiri::XML(a, nil, "UTF-8")
#⇒ #<Nokogiri::XML::Document:0x5c459d2 <SKIPPED>
#           name="Purpose" 
#           children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x5c4cc00 "ЛИЧНЫЕ">]>,
#      <SKIPPED> 
#    >]>]>]>

doc.xpath('//response/Purpose').to_s
#⇒ "<Purpose>ЛИЧНЫЕ</Purpose>"
```

Hope it helps.